# Autodesk Datamanagement API: Store Custom Objects

Tags: autodesk-data-management

I am currently trying to integrate the Autodesk Datamanagement API in my application. Now I am wondering, if I can use it as a kind of a database to store objects.

Is this possible or would it be a misue of this API?

> So basically I want to create custom items like in sharepoint. Let's say I want to create an item "Task" with the attributes "Title", "Deadline", "assigned To", "status" and store them in the Autodesk Cloud via Autodesk Datamanagement API

Comment: can you elaborate on "database to store objects"?

Comment: you can upload files and create a reference between them, this file can be a txt, for instance, but cannot yet add metadata to it. If you change the txt, you'll need to upload a new version... is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Comment: Can you create an answer, so I can accept it and mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a file and [create a relationship](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-relationships-refs-POST/) between them. This file can be a TXT, for instance, but cannot yet add metadata to it. If you change the TXT, you'll need to upload and [create a new version](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/).